# Passing two similar forms as the same type and still being able to access its objects

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, parameters

I am trying to implement another form into already complete routine.  Basically all the code is there, all I need to do is manipulate the data in a different manner.

I have a routine that looks like this for instance.
This is a paraphrase example:

```
Private Sub getReportValues(ByRef fr As frmCustomReport, ByRef ReportInfo As ReportValues)
            ReportInfo.eHeaderColor = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\FE Jupiter\MSSMonitor").GetValue("Report Equipment Header Color", "DCDCDC") 'Gainsboro
            ReportInfo.mHeaderColor = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\FE Jupiter\MSSMonitor").GetValue("Report Monitor Header Color", "FFF8DC")   'Cornsilk

fr.btnEquipColor.PickedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Hex("&HFF" & ReportInfo.eHeaderColor))
```

The problem lays with the (fr as frmCustomReport) I want to make it a system.windows.forms.form but then I would lose the ability to use its objects. I should also mention that fr is a modal dialog and that I don't want a really hacky controlcollection work around for this. Does anyone have a good direction on this?

Note Also!!! The controls I want to access on both forms are almost identical. The only diffrence is layout and some added functionality.

Comment: Oh, I don't want to move these methods over to the form itself either, this would have been my first move but its not an option in this case.

Comment: Maybe something in the manner of drawing a association between the values and their relation to both forms?

Comment: You can pass both forms as a Form object and cast them, ex. CType(fr, frmCustomReport) to access the underlying objects, but you do need to know which form you have passed.

Comment: Late binding is not an acceptable solution either I'm afraid. You can not directly affect the objects of a form.... Ex. Form.button1.text = "New text." I need to be able to do it without late binding.

Answer (score 1):

Without a little more information,it is a little hard to give a concrete example. This will work depending on the amount of interaction you need to do. Create a subroutine that accepts the Base Class as an argument, take a look at the Name value and base your conditional logic off of that using CType to cast the Form to the proper type.

```
Private Sub clickOtherFormsButton(Value As Form)

    If Value.Name = "Form3" Then
        Dim formObject As Form3 = CType(Value, Form3)
        formObject.Button1.PerformClick()
    ElseIf Value.Name = "Form2" Then
        Dim formObject As Form2 = CType(Value, Form2)
        formObject.Button1.PerformClick()
    End If

End Sub
```